# Converting heat map to .asc file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, heat-map

I have produced a number of heat maps using QGIS and I am hoping to compare their overlap using fuzzy kappa from Map Comparison Kit 3. However, the program only accepts `.asc` files or `.log` files for comparison. How would I go about saving each heat map layer as a `.asc` file?

Comment: There are a number of ASCII formats with that suffix. Have you researched which one you actually want? What have you tried?

Comment: Use the export function?

Comment: Hi, there is no option to export the layer as a .asc file

Answer (score 0):

Open the [Translate (convert format) tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#gdaltranslate), select your raster layer and choose ASC as the output format.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have previously tried that and it doesn't allow me to select the heat map layers for translation

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to provide details about your layers